Is the definition for comparable in builtin.go file wrong？
The definition is：
//comparable is an interface that is implemented by all comparable types
// (booleans, numbers, strings, pointers, channels, arrays of comparable types,
// structs whose fields are all comparable types).
// The comparable interface may only be used as a type parameter constraint,
// not as the type of a variable.  

 type comparable interface{ comparable }

What does the definition mean? Isn't it a recursive interface?

The builtin package is there for documentation purposes. It is not really imported.  According to the package docs:

Package builtin provides documentation for Go's predeclared identifiers. The items documented here are not actually in package builtin but their descriptions here allow godoc to present documentation for the language's special identifiers.


What does it mean to write like this? The interface has itself. What is this meant to express though it is not actually in package builtin？

As I said, package builtin is there only for documentation purposes. Many of the things in package builtin are specified in a certain way in the language spec, and the compiler and runtime implements them in a certain way. comparable is a special symbol recognized by the compiler, it is not defined like this as an interface.

The builtin package documentation says:

Package builtin provides documentation for Go's predeclared identifiers. The items documented here are not actually in package builtin but their descriptions here allow godoc to present documentation for the language's special identifiers.

The type declaration type comparable interface{ comparable } is not actually in the package.  It's just a placeholder for attaching the documentation.
